# Is there an open dense set $S \subset [0,1]$ such that $m(S)<1$?

Tags: measure-theory

$m$ is the Lebesgue measure. I was thinking that:
$\Bbb Q$ is dense and $m(\Bbb Q)=0<1$ but it fails to be open, but maybe I could construct an open set from this fact, or also using that $(0,1)$ is a dense and open subset but $m(0,1)=1$.

Any hints or ideas will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Fat Cantor sets, complement.

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not get your hint. Could you elaborate please ? The complement of the cantor set in $[0,1]$ has measure $1$ not less than $1$.

Comment: @Amr Seems you overlooked the first word in the hint. Fat Cantor sets are called fat because they have positive measure.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Enumerate $D=\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$. For every $n$, consider an open interval of length $2^{-n}\varepsilon$  around the $n$th element of $D$. Call $U$ the union of these intervals. Then:

- The set $U$ is open.
- The Lebesgue measure of $U$ is at most $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\varepsilon=\varepsilon$.
- The set $U$ contains $D$, hence its closure $\bar U$ contains $\bar D=[0,1]$.

Comment: If getting a subset of $[0,1]$ is important, consider $S=U\cap(0,1)$.